# How to pass parameters while triggering a package or else how to find the last modified record in a table?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, triggers, oracle10g, package

Whenever a row is modified or inserted newly in the database ( Oracle 10g), there is a trigger on one column considering it is of particular value, it triggers a package. I have a stored procedure inside that package which will need this record which triggered these. There is no column that is storing timestamps. How can we do this ? I'm sure there will be a work around. Any help is appreciated,if atleast a guidance in the right direction.

Comment: Can you show some code and what you have tried so far? Your question looks incomplete, with lots of possibly unrelated information.

Comment: I don't understand what is unrelated and it doesn't relate to any code that possibly might help you in clarifying this. Its a trigger on a column of a table which for a particular value on that column when modified or inserted new, gets triggered. When a new record is inserted, I have to find this record from inside some other package which is triggered because of this insertion.

Comment: can you show us a sample test table and your trigger code.? for your comment to jva's answer, you can identify a record (either inserted or updated) by the primary key, which in jva's example is called "id".

Comment: yes, jva's answer worked. I had read that but was skeptic that new might not worked for a modified record. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your table has a primary key ID, you can find the record by `:new.id.`

Comment: jva : your answer does hold good for new insertion. But for modified records, how can we find it ?

Comment: The same should be true for modified records. Or you can use :old.id.